# Boy who can ping from planet to planet

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I read a book in the early 80's. it's a science fiction story about a boy who can ping around the universe wearing his tunic running from the evil villain.  It seems like I remember it having kind of a long title.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! As given, your question doesn't give us much to work with. Check the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for some suggestions as to additional information you could add. Can you describe what you mean by "ping"? Is the boy teleporting from one planet to another, for instance? Is there something special or unique about his tunic, that made it one of the few things you remember? Does the evil villain also "ping"? Can you confirm this was a novel, rather than a short story? You may also want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely *Caverns: The Journeys of McGill Feighan, Book 1*, the first McGill Feighan novel by Kevin O'Donnell Jr.  McGill is a Flinger, a natural teleport who can travel or send objects up to a limiting mass anywhere in the Universe that he "knows" -- by having been there in order to memorize the location and relative velocity.  There are at least three more books -- *Reefs*, *Lava*, and *Cliffs*.

The Flinger Tunic is a distinctive identifier of Flingers, generated by an implanted device, but McGill removes his (by Flinging it out of his body) in the third book.

The first book was published in 1981, the fourth in 1986.  Internally, it seems there was an intent for the series to run longer (that is, it doesn't have what I see as a conclusion in Book 4), but no further books were published.

Comment: Beat me to it -- that was the one that popped into my head when I saw the question.